# Apache Kafka Stream to Stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Using Apache Kafka I want to pass the records I receive from topic1 to topic2 stream. But after read carefully the documentation I cannot manage to send the events to the topic2 stream. Here my code

```
 @Test
    public void topicToTopic() throws InterruptedException {
        String broker = embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString();
        String topic1 = "Consumer-topic-1";
        String topic2 = "Consumer-topic-2";

        Properties config = getSourceConfig(broker);
        Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        builder.stream(topic1, Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde))
                .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("Topic 1 Observed event:" + v))
                .mapValues((ValueMapper<String, String>) String::toUpperCase)
                .to(topic2, Produced.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
        Topology topology = builder.build();
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);
        streams.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        publishMessages(broker, topic1);

        StreamsBuilder builder1 = new StreamsBuilder();
        builder1.stream(topic2, Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde))
                .foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println("key: " + key + " -> " + value));

        Topology topology1 = builder1.build();
        KafkaStreams streams1 = new KafkaStreams(topology1, config);
        streams1.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        streams.close();
        streams1.close();
    }
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Regards

Comment: Kafka Streams has TopologyTestDriver if you want to write a unit test

Comment: I’m using embedded Kafka

Comment: I can see that, but it's not really an appropriate library for Kafka Streams unit testing https://www.confluent.io/blog/testing-kafka-streams/

Comment: Agree, let’s pretend I’m using this like in Integration test. Anyway I expect it should not work anyway.

Comment: Can you please share the publishMessages function?

Comment: https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/kafka/src/test/java/com/politrons/kafka/KafkaStreamFeature.java Thanks!!

Comment: Seems fine, except for the calling get() method for every single message. Have you tried producing before starting the first topology? Or add `consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest` config to the Streams configs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start the consumer stream before publishing message